# ASP.Net C# - Navigation Shows even when logged out

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

[image]

Hi, above is a snapshot of my problem. I really couldn't ind a way to disable the navigation links when the page loads, when I log off it works just fine, but there are instances that this shows. How could i fix this?? The nav is located on Site.Master page. Thank you!

This is what I have on Site.Master's mark up w/ relation to the nav bar

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="Default.aspx">IR</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                <asp:LoginView id="lvLoginRegister" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <%--<li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>--%>
                            <%--<li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log out</a></li>--%>
                        </ul>
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="NavPanel" runat="server">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li> </li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                ...
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">1<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                ....
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            ...
                            <li><a runat="server" >3/a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Welcome, <%=doctor%> !</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/Account/Login" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this on my code behind:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The code below helps to protect against XSRF attacks
        var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey];
        Guid requestCookieGuidValue;
        if (requestCookie != null && Guid.TryParse(requestCookie.Value, out requestCookieGuidValue))
        {
            // Use the Anti-XSRF token from the cookie
            _antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value;
            Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;
        }
        else
        {
            // Generate a new Anti-XSRF token and save to the cookie
            _antiXsrfTokenValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;

            var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Value = _antiXsrfTokenValue
            };
            if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL && Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                responseCookie.Secure = true;
            }
            Response.Cookies.Set(responseCookie);
        }

        Page.PreLoad += master_Page_PreLoad;
    }

    protected void master_Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Set Anti-XSRF token
            ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] = Page.ViewStateUserKey;
            ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] = Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            // Validate the Anti-XSRF token
            if ((string)ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != _antiXsrfTokenValue
                || (string)ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] != (Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Unnamed_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Session.Clear();
        Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    }
```

Which to be honest I really don't understand. Its the default template of asp.

Comment: share your code please

Comment: @JitendraTiwari hi! updated my post, i'm using asp template. So I really dont understand whats happening. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace code behind Page_Load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Request.IsAuthenticate)
   {
       NavPanel.Visible=false;
   }
}
```

Hope this help.